# $n$ integers, $a_i a_j +1$ all perfect squares

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, products, square-numbers

Find all numbers $n$ so that there exists $n$ integers $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$: 
$a_i \ge 2$ and $a_i\cdot a_j +1 (\forall i\not = j)$ are all perfect squares.

Comment: Look up 0,1,3,8,120 in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (oeis.org)

Comment: it's so useful. Thank you :D

Comment: so what about $a_i\cdot a_j - 1$ are all perfect squares?

Comment: You should also check A.Dujella's web page on [Diophantine $m$-tuples](https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/~duje/dtuples.html).

Comment: there is an old IMO problem, with tuples 2, 5, 13, d. I generalized it last year. It's amazing to see the original unsolved problem :D