# How do you solve this problem of square numbers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Whether there are different positive integers
> $a_1,a_2,a_3,b_1,b_2,b_3$ , such that $a_ib_j+1\ (1\leq i,j\leq3)$ is a perfect square
> number?

I think there is an infinite number that satisfy this property. Someone gave a general idea as follows:

1.Take $(a,b,c)\in \mathbb{Z}^3$ satisfy $\text{gcd}(a^2-1,b^2-1,c^2-1)=1$ and write $a_1=a^2-1,a_2=b^2-1,a_3=c^2-1$.Consider elliptic curve $E:y^2=(a_1x+1)(a_2x+1)(a_3x+1)$ (**Of course, this form is not an elliptic curve, which is the biggest flaw of this method: it is only an elliptic curve if it is defined on open set of $\text{Spec}\ \mathbb{Z}[a_1,a_2,a_3]_{\langle a_i,a_i-a_j\rangle}\ (1\leq i,j\leq 3)$, then the following could all be wrong! So don't continue if you don't think it's true, it's just someone else's idea**). If $x(P)=0,1$ then $P\in \mathbb{Z}^2$ and not torsion in $E(\mathbb{Q})$.

2.If $P$ is not a torsion ,then define $1\mapsto P,n\mapsto [n]P$ to give isomorphism $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow G\subset E(\mathbb{Q})$ and notes that $\text{gcd}(a_ix+1,a_jx+1)|a_i-a_j$ is independent of $x$. We know that the p-adic expansion of $x$ in $G$ is periodic, so we can prove that there is an arithmetic sequence $\{c_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ that satisfies $x(f^{-1}(c_n))\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $x(f^{-1}(c_n))\equiv 1\ (\text{mod}\ a_i-a_j)$. Thus we can take $b_1=x(f^{-1}(c_n)),b_2=x(f^{-1}(c_{n+1})),b_3=x(f^{-1}(c_{n+2}))$ as solution to the equation.

I don't have a good proof for all of this, but the purpose of my question is to find a very elementary and wonderful proof. Thank you for your help.

Comment: do you know any solutions?

Comment: See this [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1514308/n-integers-a-i-a-j-1-all-perfect-squares?noredirect=1)!

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a_%7Bi%7Db_%7Bj%7D%2B1%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aperfect%20squares&p=1), I found Dietrich's linked post of [$n$ integers, $a_i a_j +1$ all perfect squares](/q/1514308) (with it having a comment linking to [Diophantine $m$-tuples](https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/~duje/dtuples.html)), as well as the related [Multiples that are one less than Squares](/q/1607501), and AoPS thread [a_ia_j+1 is perfect square](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1642180p10350697).

Comment: This is simpler than the link given above --- $a_ia_j+1$ can be squared